# How to use a different post model in Web Api odata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

When posting to my Web Api post method, I would like to use a different model than for example the Get method. My get method uses for example a `UserViewModel`, but for the post method I want to use `CreateUserCommand`.

How can I do this?

Comment: what have you tried thus far? Code snippets would be useful.

Comment: @Brad, nothing. I have no idea where to start. If I just use `CreateUserCommand`, the command is always null. Is it what I want even possible?